# How to generate several functions using a for loop in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to generate several functions with different parameter i (see below) using a for loop, but it seems that all these functions are using the last item of i's. Could anyone tell me how to handle this?

This is a simplified example. I actually need to generate more than 200 functions with different parameters.

```
funs = ()
for i in range(2):
    f = lambda x: x+i
    funs += (f,)
```

Then it turns out that the two functions do the same thing:

```
funs[0](1)
```

Output: 2

```
funs[1](1)
```

Output: 2

But I expect the first function to give a result of 1 rather than 2.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you can generate the functions you can do it with one. Python functions are very dynamic.

Comment: See [Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result) from the Python FAQ.

Answer (score 6):

The reason you're getting the same result for all the functions is because `i` is not local to the lambdas, but is defined in the outer scope, and it is accessed when the lambda is called - not when it is defined. At the end of the loop, the value of `i` is 1 and thus, it uses 1 for every call to the lambda functions.

Jean-Francois Fabre gave one good solution but I personally prefer this:

```
list_ = []
for i in range(2):
    f = lambda x, n=i: x+n
    list_.append(f)
```

Answer (score 5):

you have to break the dynamic binding to `i`, for instance by wrapping 2 lambdas together:

```
f = (lambda p : lambda x: x+p)(i)
```

that way, the value of `i` is captured, and functions hold a copy of `i`

Aside: I wouldn't use `tuple` to create the list for performance reasons when appending to `funs` (`funs = ()` => `funs = []`)